# How to terminate a Firebase callable function that does not need to return anything?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This example:

A function to increment a `VIEWCOUNT` collection.

No need to `return` anything. Also there's no need to `await` for the `firestore...update()` call.

```
export const onCall_updateViewCount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const { id } = data;
  const VIEWCOUNT = COLLECTIONS.VIEWCOUNT;

  admin.firestore().collection(VIEWCOUNT).doc(VIEWCOUNT).update({
    [id]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });

  return;
});
```

What is the proper way to terminate this function? Is it fine to end with void `return`?

Is the void `return;` necessary? Will it continue running until timeout if I don't return anything? Like it does on `onRequest` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function must return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  You can't return early - you must wait for the completion, otherwise Cloud Functions might forcibly shut down the function, and it will never complete.

For callable functions in particular, you must also return a promise that resolves with the data to serialize to the client app.  It's better to be specific about this than try to serialize the result of some unknown promise results.

```
export const onCall_updateViewCount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  const { id } = data;
  const VIEWCOUNT = COLLECTIONS.VIEWCOUNT;

  return admin.firestore().collection(VIEWCOUNT).doc(VIEWCOUNT).update({
    [id]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  })
  .then(() => {
    return { result: "OK" };
  });
});
```

Be sure to review the [documentation for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

Comment: Thanks. I know that my function may be terminated before the `update()` promise completes (successfully or not) and I'll not be able to do anything with the result. But the fact that the function may be shut down before the promise completes should not stop the `update()` call from doing its thing, right? Given the fact that the call was already made. Will `firebase-admin` emit some kind of `cancel` trigger if its process gets terminated? I know this is probably not good practice to don't wait the result, but I would like to know more how it would behave in this scenario.

Comment: When Cloud Function terminates your function, it might stop your update from completing.  That's why you need to return a promise - to tell it when it's done and safe to clean up.